# How to genernate position-dependent code for executable file when linking with shared library in gcc?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, elf, pic

I'm learning ELF.I want to find the difference of elf format between position-dependent executable file and position-independent executable file when linking shared library.

But I can't genernate  position-dependent code for executable file when linking with shared library.

```
/*Lib.c*/
static int a;
extern int b;
int c=1;
extern void exit();
void set_value()
{
    a=1;
    b=1;
    c=1;
}
void run()
{
    set_value();
    exit();
}
```

Fist,use gcc to genrnate a shared dynamic library:

```
gcc -m32 -nostdlib -o Lib.so Lib.c
```

Note that I don't use -fpic to generate position-independent code for Lib.so.

Now，I have another file main.c which need to link with Lib.so:

```
/*main.c*/
extern void run();
int b=2;
void nomain()
{
    run();
}
void exit()
{
    asm("int $0x80 \n\t"
        ::"a"(1),"b"(42));

}
```

use following command to link main.c with Lib.so:

```
gcc  -m32 -e nomain  -nostartfiles  -fno-builtin  -o a.out main.c ./Lib.so
```

Howerve,gcc will compile main.c to position-independent code defaultly when link with shared library even this library don't use pic.

I wonder whether gcc have some option to genernate position-dependent for executable file?

I post the section information for Lib.so and a.out.We can see there are '.plt' and '.got.plt' section in a.out which mean a.out use PIC.

```
  /*Section for Lib.so*/
  Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        000000b4 0000b4 00003c 04   A  2   0  4
  [ 2] .dynsym           DYNSYM          000000f0 0000f0 000090 10   A  3   1  4
  [ 3] .dynstr           STRTAB          00000180 000180 000030 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 4] .rel.dyn          REL             000001b0 0001b0 000028 08   A  2   0  4
  [ 5] .text             PROGBITS        000001d8 0001d8 000033 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 6] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0000120c 00020c 000078 08  WA  3   0  4
  [ 7] .got.plt          PROGBITS        00001284 000284 00000c 04  WA  0   0  4
  [ 8] .data             PROGBITS        00001290 000290 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 9] .bss              NOBITS          00001294 000294 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [10] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 000294 00002e 00      0   0  1
  [11] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0002c2 00006a 00      0   0  1
  [12] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 00055c 000170 10     13  15  4
  [13] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0006cc 000057 00      0   0  1
  /*Section for a.out*/
  Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        080480f4 0000f4 000013 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        08048108 000108 000034 04   A  3   0  4
  [ 3] .dynsym           DYNSYM          0804813c 00013c 000070 10   A  4   1  4
  [ 4] .dynstr           STRTAB          080481ac 0001ac 000037 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 5] .rel.plt          REL             080481e4 0001e4 000008 08   A  3   6  4
  [ 6] .plt              PROGBITS        080481ec 0001ec 000020 04  AX  0   0  4
  [ 7] .text             PROGBITS        0804820c 00020c 000020 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 8] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0804922c 00022c 000090 08  WA  4   0  4
  [ 9] .got.plt          PROGBITS        080492bc 0002bc 000010 04  WA  0   0  4
  [10] .data             PROGBITS        080492cc 0002cc 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [11] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 0002d0 00002e 00      0   0  1
  [12] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0002fe 00006d 00      0   0  1
  [13] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0005c4 000160 10     14  15  4
  [14] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 000724 000051 00      0   0  1
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm learning ELF.I want to find the difference of elf format between position-dependent executable file and position-independent executable file when linking shared library.

Comment: Your platform's `strip` *might* be able to remove relocation information.

Comment: I'm not trying to remove relocation information

Answer (score 0):

You should compile your `Lib.so` with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -m32 -shared -Wl,-soname,Lib.so -o Lib.so Lib.c`.

What you did here is just to generate a normal program without relocation information.

Look at this [tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN95) to know more about dynamic libraries.

**Note**: Also, don't forget to set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in order to point to `Lib.so`.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal program without relocation information",acctually there exist .rela.dyn in a.out and Lib.so.

Comment: I'm sorry,but I think you may not understand my question.

Comment: I really don't see your point... moreover, using the `asm` primitive in the program cannot be done together with generating PIC code. The explanation of this is quite simple. It is because the compiler will not control what you write inside the `asm(...)`, so it can't ensure that you will generate `-fPIC` code.

Comment: You can use `asm` just fine inside PIC code.  You just can't use certain registers on certain architectures.